# Getting Powershell error Cannot handle XX packages. The limit is 63

Tags: powershell

I recently added some programs to look for in a script.
Now when I run it, I get the following error:
get-package : PackageManagement cannot handle '76' packages.The limit is 63.

I have tried modifying it and if I drop some programs, it works. I looked on Google and Technet with no success..

Here is the script:

```
get-package 'Microsoft Edge','Mitel Connect', '*7-Zip*','*Cylance*','*Office Profession*','*Google*','Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client','Microsoft Teams','Multipresenter','*Foxit*','*Java*','Local Administrator Password Solution','Autodesk AutoCAD LT','SOLIDWORKS 2021','NEWTON'  | select name,version >> "c:\Temp\Programs.txt"
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction to fix this issue?

Comment: Your problem is the `Get-Package`, as the error message indicates. Break it up into multiple statements.

Comment: You could also place names of programs in an array and go with for each loop. This could possibly circumvent your problem

Comment: I tried breaking it up but when it does the output, for every new command, it skips a few lines and then puts Name,Version and lists the new ones. Is there a way to combine them all so it is 1 list and not broken into multiple?

Comment: I did as suggested bit I am getting this...  Its not combining them...                       Name           Version      
----           -------  Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2019 - en-us 16.0.10373.20050
Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2019 - ja-jp 16.0.10373.20050
Microsoft Teams                                 1.5.00.21668    



Name           Version      
----           -------      
Microsoft Edge 106.0.1370.42

Comment: I got myself confused: even separate `Get-Package` calls in a script go to the same pipeline and their output objects are therefore normally formatted together, so now I'm unsure what caused the symptom described in your first comment. The limited formatting in comments makes it hard to understand your latest comment. Please update your question with your latest attempt and the resulting (undesired) output.

Comment: As an aside re formatting in comments: you can only use _inline_ code formatting (`\`...\``) with no support for line breaks. Unlike in posts, there must be _no whitespace_ after the opening and before the closing delimiter. _Multi_-`\`` delimiters for support of embedded `\`` chars. are supported (e.g. `\`\`"\`n"\`\``). Unlike in posts, ``\`` can alternatively be used to escape `\``, which, due to the no-whitespace requirement, is a must if you want to produce something like `\`enclosed\``. To produce a formatted ``\`` alone, use `\`\`\\`\``